Finding data for primary criminological research - help!
I'm a PhD student in Criminology and this will be my first experience of undertaking a substantial independent research project. I'm in the process of designing my project, but the problem is that I just can't understand how or where I can collect data from.
I've read so many articles where criminologists are using primary data, usually gathered from interviews, from surveys, or from getting access to police/intelligence/court records. I've also read loads of research guides that say 'you can use X sources' (again mostly surveys, interviews, law enforcement records etc.), so together these tell me the types of sources that I should be thinking of using. However, in none of these readings have I found any guidance on actually how to get hold of such data e.g. who to contact to set up interviews, who to contact to get hold of police records etc. I'm completely lost and stumped by this, since clearly I need to actually find a viable source to undertake the research, yet there's no information on how to get access to sources.
In case context is useful, my project will be focused on the UK. I'm torn between undertaking a project on either organised crime or post-prison experiences, but hard to decide this without knowing what sort of data/sources/information is out there!
Final note: this isn't something I can address with my supervisor, since they have been very unhelpful and ignore my requests for help/guidance since they are busy working on a number of different projects (in fact, I've only met them once and never get email responses). I'm also not part of a lab, so don't have any peers to ask.

The reasons you've listed why you cannot ask your supervisors are actually reasons why you absolutely should ask your supervisor. Not just about this topic, but also the general working relation. You cannot do a PhD with a supervisor who does not talk to you, or put differently with a supervisor who you don't know how to talk to.

Hi @PeterFlom, not sure what this means as I'm new here (new to StackExchange completely). Are you suggesting I remove the post and post it somewhere else?

I think you can do that. I think it belongs on the OpenData site, which is all about finding data.

Is all of this data open? Nevertheless, VTC as it's about the content of research.

@PeterFlom OP doesn't seem to be asking about open data but about how to collect new data.

Ooops .... You are right.

Hi all, very confused here as a new poster and don't understand how my query is about Open Data, but I'll see if I can figure out where else to post instead...
